# How to add footer in a particular frame only in beamer?

Tags: beamer

Suppose I don't want to add footer in all frame. I want to add it in a particular frame of a beamer. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Suppose I don't want  to add footer in all frame. I want to add it in a particular frame of a beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you add a footline within a group, frames outside the group won't be affected:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{whatever}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: @ATANUMAITY You're welcome! But for you next question, please have a look at [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)